# Json_LD или shcema.org?

Tags: seo, schema.org

На сайте размещаются вопросы и пользователи оставляют ответы.

1. Какую микроразметку предпочтительней использовать (Json_LD или shcema.org)?
2. Возможно лучше использовать и ту и ту одновременно?
3. Если на странице нет ответов на вопрос, микроразметка должна отсутствовать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Schema является справочной библиотекой для структурированных данных. JSON-LD является форматом структурированных данных и в каждом скрипте имеет ссылку на Schema:

   "@context": "https://schema.org"

**[Гугл рекомендует JSON-LD](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/advanced/structured-data/intro-structured-data#structured-data-format)**:

> JSON-LD* (рекомендуется)

**[АПИ Гугл Знаний Граф](https://developers.google.com/knowledge-graph)** также использует JSON-LD:

> The API uses standard schema.org types and is compliant with the
> JSON-LD specification.  API использует стандартные типы schema.org и
> соответствует спецификации JSON-LD.

2. Можно для представления разных сущностей (не дублированного содержания). Для связывания содержания в различных форматах вы можете использовать элемент [@id для JSON-LD](https://w3c.github.io/json-ld-syntax/#node-identifiers) и элемент [itemid](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/itemid) для микродата.
3. Schema создана не только для представления вопросов и ответов. Эта справочная библиотека имеет множество возможностей для представления **[различных субъектов содержания](https://schema.org/docs/full.html)**. В свою очередь, **[Гугл говорит](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/advanced/structured-data/sd-policies#relevance)**:

> **Релевантность**
>
> Структурированные данные должны в точности отражать контент страницы.

Вы можете представлять в структурированных данных различные субъекты содержания ваших страниц, включая и вопросы и ответы.